# Getting the ResourceConfig instance of a Jersey server

Tags: java, jersey, httpserver

I work with a Jersey server 1.18 and I want to add a `ContainerResponseFilter` to the server.

In order to do it, when creating the server, instead of using just the URL, like here:

```
server = HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI);
```

I need to also pass an instance of `ResourceConfig`, like this:

```
server = HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI, resourceConfig);
```

The problem is that I don't know how I can get the default resource config which Jersey uses as default, so I can add the filter...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`ResourceConfig` javadoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html). If you look at the "Direct Known Subclasses" you will see an implementation of the abstract `ResourceConfig`. If you click that link, you will see more subclasses, and click those links and see more, etc. Read the jacdocs for each of those subclasses and decide which one best fits your needs.

For example the [`PackagesResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/PackagesResourceConfig.html) is an implementation that allows you to scan packages for `@Path` and `@Provider` classes to automatically register. Just pass the package(s) to the constructor

```
ResourceConfig config = new PackagesResourceConfig("the.packages", "to.scan");
```

Comment: Just to add, I would imagine the default implementation would be the [`ClasspathResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ClasspathResourceConfig.html) that will scan the entire classpath. Not 100 percent sure, but it sounds right. But I would just use the `PackagesResourceConfig` so it doesn't waste time scanning the entire classpath

Comment: no, class path scanning is not the default option. see https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.17/user-guide.html chapter 2.2

Comment: @Meiko what section?

Comment: @Meiko That link says nothing about HttpServerFactory or any _default_ option. It is just an example. The way the OP is using the HttpServerFactory passing only a URI, the only reasonable implementation that would bootstrap the app is to scan the classpath for resource classes and providers, since no ResourceConfig is being passed to the factory method. That's why I said that "it sounds right"

Comment: yes, you are right. I did not understand your problem.